# Default parameters in dynamically defined methods

Tags: ruby

I am trying to dynamically define methods and pass a parameter to it. This is what I have so far:

```
class Commands
end

@commands = Commands.new

def route(name, &block)
  Commands.send(:define_method, name, &block)
end

route 'foo' do
  puts 'oh hai'
  puts data
end
```

When `route` is called, this is what I expect to be executed:

```
data = {name: 'foo', optional: 'bar'}
@commands.send(data['name'].to_sym, data)
```

This fails because `data` isn't defined unless I do something like:

```
route 'foo' do |data|
  puts 'oh hai'
  puts data
end
```

Is there a way to pass a default parameter? Seems like it's sinatrarb does it, but I haven't been able to make head or tails from the code yet.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pass a default parameter".

Comment: Clear as mud? :), sorry about the unclear question. Part of the issue is definitely that I don't know what what is the underlying question I should be asking.

The answers look on target, so I'll experiment and update my question either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I suspect that the functionality you're looking for is the sort usually achieved with [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) and friends. `instance_eval` evaluates the given block in the context of its callee, so that the callee's instance methods and instance variables are available inside the block.

Here's a really elementary example:

```
"foo".instance_eval do
  puts size
  puts upcase
end
# -> 3
# -> FOO
```

`size` and `upcase` aren't parameters we've given to the block, they're methods that are already available in the context of the String object.

With that in mind, you might start with something like this:

```
class Route
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(name)
    @data = { name: name, optional: "bar" }
  end
end

rt = Route.new("foo")

rt.instance_eval do
  puts 'oh hai'
  puts data
end
# -> oh hai
# -> {:name=>"foo", :optional=>"bar"}
```

Here we've defined a Route class whose instances can serve as a context in which to evaluate blocks given to the `route` method:

```
def route(name, &block)
  rt = Route.new(name)
  Commands.send(:define_method, name) do
    rt.instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

route 'foo' do
  puts 'oh hai'
  puts data
end

route 'qux' do
  puts "My name is %{name} and optional is %{optional}" % data
end

@commands = Commands.new
@commands.foo
# -> oh hai
# -> {:name=>"foo", :optional=>"bar"}

@commands.qux
# -> My name is qux and optional is bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The block is what you are passing to `route` method; you are free to pass whatever you want, hence ruby won’t complain against any number of parameters (till the `@commands.foo` is actually called.)

One might assign a default value to block parameter:

```
λ = lambda do |data = 'hello'|
  puts data
end
```

and pass this lambda to `route`:

```
route 'foo', &λ
#⇒ "hello"
```

AFAIK, there is no way to explicitly assign local variable in foreign `binding` using some kind of hack like:

```
block.binding.local_variable_set(:data, 'hello')
```